# Access file under test resources through test application properties

Tags: spring, spring-properties

I have two files under the following folder hierarchy `src/test/resources/folderA/fileA` and `src/test/resources/folderA/fileB`. I have a reference to these files from the `application.properties` under test resources (`src/test/resources/application.properties`). The reference is the following:

```
propertyA=classpath:/folderA/fileB
propertyA=classpath:/folderA/fileA
```

Unfortunately this is apparently not working. It breaks with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath:/folderA/fileA (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried also the following:

```
propertyA=classpath:folderA/fileB
propertyA=/folderA/fileB
propertyA=folderA/fileB
```

and they are also not working. So what is the appropriate way to refer a resource file from test application properties in order to be property loaded?